# Token based authentication and authoriozation for Apache Tomcat servlets

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, oauth, single-sign-on

**Background**: Our current technology architecture includes Tomcat Servlets that do backend activities and Codeigniter PHP which handles the presentation layer. So when a particular page is loaded, the Codeigniter View invokes the Controller which constructs the servlet URL with necessary input parameters and invokes the URL and gets the response and passes it back to the View so that the page is rendered.

**Issue:** User information and login credentials are stored in database and is validated by PHP front end. There is no authentication for the Tomcat servlets and in cases where we need user information in the backend, the user id is passed as a parameter to the backend.

Currently Tomcat and PHP resides on the same server and we have used firewall port based restrictions to ensure that servlets can be invoked only from within the server to secure the servlets.

**Help required** : We are looking to implement token based authentication and authorization mechanism for the servlets. If we can get some sort of existing library that we can easily plug-in to our servlets, that would be ideal. Otherwise please guide what would be the best solution to implement without too much code changes but would effectively secure the backend servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Cássio Mazzochi Molin have a nice articel about the topic : [Token-based authentication with JAX-RS 2.0](http://cassiomolin.com/token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-2-0/)